# Unable to fetch data with useQuery hook for a remote query that has some @client variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

Given below is the query that fetches a list of products and stores it in the apollo-client local cache. It retrieves a list of `products` and the list of `images` for every product

```
const GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
  query Products($cursor: String, $query: String, $imageCount: Int = 100) {
    products(first: 9, after: $cursor, query: $query) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          id
          selected @client
          title
          description
          images(first: $imageCount) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                originalSrc
                selected @client
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I have a bunch of `products` with `selected: true` and each of this products will have one or more `images` with `selected: true`.

The `GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY` is being used by a `ProductsList` component that fetches the products and renders it. This is working fine. When the user selects some product, the `selected` is marked as true in the local cache and the `ProductsList` component rerenders. So far so good.

I have another component where I need to use the same `GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY` to fetch the products but **only from the cache**. This component should listen to the list of products in the cache and whenever something changes in the cache, it should rerender. I was trying the following to no avail

```
export default () => {
  const { data: productsData = {} } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY, { fetchPolicy: "cache-only" });
  const { selectedProducts = [] } = productsData;
  //Render selected products
}
```

During initial render, the query is executed and nothing is returned as expected.

- After ProductsList fetched the list of products and populated the cache, I expected the render function to be called as I was listening on the query but it did not happen
- I manually affected a render by changing some other props so that the useQuery will be triggered. But I still did not get any products from the cache inspite of having it there.

Can anyone please explain where I've gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching two different queries -- you would need to ensure that not only the query is the same but that the variables passed to both hooks are the same as well.

Think of it this way. When you fetch, for example, 20 products

```
products(first: 20)
```

Apollo normalizes the result when storing it in the cache. Each product is stored individually and assigned a key. Then the `products` field is associated with those keys. However, imagine if you then queried for 21 products:

```
products(first: 21)
```

If Apollo ignored the argument values passed to the field, it would treat this as a cache hit and just return the 20 products associated with the earlier query. Luckily, it doesn't do that. Each list of keys is associated not just with the field but also with the arguments provided to the field. If the arguments change, and that combination of arguments isn't already in the cache, then Apollo knows it needs to fetch the data from the server.

Comment: Actually I did not pass any values for the variables. So this means that `first` will be 9 in both cases. `cursor` and `query` are not being passed too. Wondering if it is something related to this issue https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3816

Comment: Are you sure `cursor` and `query` are undefined? For example, is `query` initially an empty string?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this was the case. I don't have the code now as I went with the alternate way of maintaining a seperate data structure for selected products and images. That worked for me. I will try once again later. Anyways, is the above approach that I was trying the right way to go about attaining this functionality of nested selections?

Comment: Nested fields like this are great for derived fields, but kind of a pain when working with actual state. The handful of times I've worked with a similar situation, I usually kept the local state at the root, which is what it sounds like you ended up doing. Not as elegant but easier to maintain.